# Idiom: "bulky and leaky"

Tags: idiom-meaning

What is the meaning and origin of the idiom "bulky and leaky"? I ran into it in the sentence:

> Java already has somewhat a (bulky and leaky) type of closure: anonymous inner classes

---

There is another "*bulky and leaky*" citation from the internet I cannot see direct meaning:

> Loan waivers to farmers are expensive, and do not solve any problems in the long term. What the farmer needs is a guaranteed monthly income. He should not be worried about the cost of production. The government should subsidize that and let cheap grain reach all citizens, especially the poor. The PDS is **bulky and leaky**, and it should be replaced by cheap retail prices for all, subsidized at the point of production, not the consumption side. This will incentivize farmers to stay in agri.

PDS for public distribution system - "The Indian food security system was established by the Government of India ... subsidized food and non-food items to India's poor" (from Wikipedia).

Comment: I wouldn't call this an idiom I would just call it a description used here. As I read each word and worked out what it means. And this is actually a discussion about the java language and isn't suitable here

Comment: I think it's coincidental that the two quotes both use "bulky and leaky"; as @WendyG mentions, bulky and leaky are separate attributes of a Java feature.

Comment: "bulky and leaky" are two different words,  if we use these two word together, that means we want to describing a system, that is very vast but has  loophole to maintain the things

Comment: Do you mind to write this as an answer I could upvote and later submit if there was not opposite answer?

Comment: The first sentence isn't grammatical. If you remove parenthetical information, the resulting sentence should still make sense.